# How to understand the output of the df command

Tags: disk-usage, disk

I have a dedicated server to host my website.

When I run the `df -h` command I get the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  322M  2.9G  11% /run
/dev/md2         20G  8.1G   11G  45% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        487M   29M  429M   7% /boot
/dev/md3         90G   22G   64G  26% /home
```

The commercial denomination of my server is: `E3-SSD-2-32 - E3-1225v2 - 32GB - SoftRaid 3x120GB SSD`. It is supposed to have 3 SSD drives of 120GB each. But I can't see this information in the output of the df command.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BVHTUFsc it seems that this command is closer to what I was expecting. The /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc disks look like they are the ones. Was I misunderstanding the `df -h` command?

Comment: the `df` command only shows you filesystem sizes.  To get the real disk capacities and partitions you would look at the output of `fdisk`.  From your pastebin (you should copy all of that into your question) it would appear that you do indeed have three 120G disks, but you seem to have a software RAID on top of them.  The contents of `/proc/mdstat` should have some information about your software RAID (also check out the `mdadm` command).

Answer (score 1):

You do have three drives, but they seem to be connected in RAID1 with one hot spare. Consider:

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         4096   1050623   1046528  511M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         1050624  42008575  40957952 19.5G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3        42008576 233383935 191375360 91.3G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda4       233383936 234430463   1046528  511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

The sizes of sda1, sda2 and sda3 match those of the md1, md2, md3 devices. If they were RAID5 you'd see a total of 240 GB, instead you see 120 GB.

This indicates in my opinion that sda and sdb are connected in RAID1, so that they show together as 120 GB overall, while sdc is kept in reserve, and isn't seen at all.

You can verify this by running `mdadm --detail /dev/md1`. I expect something like

```
       Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 511 MiB
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 3    <--------

             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1    <--------

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1

       2       8       33        -      spare         /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: BTW: Without the `mdadm` output, you can't be sure its 2-disk RAID1 + spare; also possible (and a more reliable config) would be 3-disk RAID1 (that is, *two* mirrors — RAID1 often only has one mirror, but it allows one or more). (The downside there is slightly lower write performance + wear on the 3rd SSD). Also, your example output is sort-of *without* a spare—there should be a `2       8      33        -      spare   /dev/sdc1` at the end

Comment: (I fixed your example output. You're missing a bunch of fields, but I'm guessing you just omitted irrelevant ones.)

Comment: Here's the output for `mdadm --detail /dev/md1`: https://pastebin.com/jCm5Sv2V

Comment: @MonsieurNinja that's 3-disk RAID1, so you have three copies of the data, protecting you from up to two disks failing (and, as always with RAID, providing no protection against a mistaken `rm -Rf`; please have backups too). BTW: Check the other md devices as well, they can be different.

Comment: Ok I get it. I just checked /dev/md2: https://pastebin.com/1TNP1HUP and /dev/md3 https://pastebin.com/Xfd4KTBY. It seems that they all add up to 120GB.